# Android ContentProvider with Services

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider

I have a ContentProvider subclass doing all my database work, and a Service that is running in the background.

I can't seem to be able to bind a Service to the ContentProvider. Can I call a method from the service within the ContentProvider at all, or is there a way to bind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I binded the service in the onCreate() method

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreate() {

        mContext = getContext();

        .. do other things

        doBindService();

        return true;
    }
```

and then used the context to actually bind the service

```
void doBindService() {

        mContext.bindService(new Intent(mContext,
                SomeService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

I don't unbind from the service, but it seems to work ok